# Rails 3 - Active_admin select nested object in many to many

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, activeadmin

I have two models. Deals and Stores.
I want to add already created Deals when creating a Store.
I want to add already created Sores when creating a Deal.
I am trying to use f.has_many, but I can't make it working.

My relationship is built using   has_and_belongs_to_many :deals and   has_and_belongs_to_many :stores (in the models)

My store custom form has the following:

```
f.inputs "Deals" do
    f.has_many :deals do |deal|
         deal.input :id, :as => :select, :include_blank => false
    end
end
```

I don't know how to add deals to the store.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking, but do you have an

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :deals   #, :allow_destroy => true
```

declaration in your Store model, and an

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :stores
```

declaration in your Deals model?

You may want to check these two pages:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic (search in the page for  accepts_nested_attributes_for)